# vue html interpolation ReferenceError

Tags: html, vue.js, environment-variables, interpolation, bitbucket-pipelines

so i put this in my `public/index.html`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   rg4js("apiKey", "<%= VUE_APP_RAYGUN_API_KEY %>");
   rg4js("enableCrashReporting", true);
</script>
```

and in my `.env` already have the variable:

`VUE_APP_RAYGUN_API_KEY=qzltkC0KuN1234`

it's all **working well in my local**, but when i want to deploy it into aws via bitbucket pipelines, it says

`ReferenceError: VUE_APP_RAYGUN_API_KEY is not defined`

under `npm run test:unit`

do you have any idea what the issue is about?

Comment: Did you add env-variables to your  deploy configuration file? I didn't worked with bitbucket but I worked with Gitlab and there in ```yaml``` files along with deploy configuration you should pass env-variables.

Answer (score 1):

Your `.env` file in local only. It should *not* be committed to your git repository, and nothing will use it.

In order to use environment variables for your bitbucket pipelines, you have to declare them on bitbucket directly: on the pipeline.yml editor, there is an option explicitly called "Add variables". Declare your variables here.

> You can also declare them globally in Your Repository > Settings > Repository variables

You can then use them in the pipeline using `$MY_VAR`. **Those variables are only usable within the bitbucket pipeline steps.**

[image: Bitbucket pipeline interface]

For the variables to be accessible from your vue app, your have to expose them as the following in your build step:

```yaml
- step:
   name: Deploy
   deployment: production
   script:
      - yarn build
        variables:
           MY_VAR: $MY_VAR
           MY_API_KEY: $MY_API_KEY
```